# User Interactive Core Graphics line without memory warning/crash

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, didreceivememorywarning

I'm working on a project that involves users interacting with straight lines rendered in Core Graphics, on top of a UIImage. Each end of the line has a "handle" for the user to interact with. When dragged, `setNeedsDisplay` is called and the line is re-drawn since the length and angle change.

I'm using the following code to redraw the line. It's pretty straightforward, but I'm starting think that Core Graphics might not be the right approach to this.

The following is called by `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawLines {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 6.0);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pointA.x, pointA.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pointB.x, pointB.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }
```

EDIT:
The problem that I'm facing is that when I drag this item around quickly, memory usage spikes, I get a memory warning, and then it crashes. Xcode says "Terminated due to memory pressure."

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: can you elaborate why you think core graphics is not right for this or why do you think memory problems arise?

Comment: In order for the line to be updated in real time, as the user drags the handle the gesture recognizer is constantly causing `setNeedsDisplay` to be called. In Xcodes's debug navigator I can see the memory usage spike, and then I'll get a memory warning and eventually a crash if I keep dragging the handle around.

Comment: if you want to update the UI to reflect the new line, there is no other way.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this, but does that mean that there is no way to make a user-interactive line in Core Graphics without causing a crash?
What I'm trying to make is essentially like a line tool in most image editing software. If Core Graphics isn't the best way to do this, could you recommend a betters solution?

Comment: if you crash, you should give the crash details in your question. CoreGraphics as such shouldn't just crash.

Comment: the above shouldn't be responsible for the memory spikes, you must also do something else.

Comment: I was able to isolate the problem a bit more, and it seems that calling `setNeedsDisplay` repeatedly is what's causing the memory problem. Thanks anyway, @Volker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The size of the UIView was just too big. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on such a huge UIView WILL cause a memory spike and crash. Apple used to limit UIView to 1024x1024. While this is no longer the limit, they still recommend keeping the size down to keeps memory footprint low.

source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html